# jQuery length enumeration for each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 7 rows with characters in each of them that I would like to display the count for in another set of 7 rows. \

For example for first #actual .list item, I would like it to display 4 characters in the #years .list, for the second #actual .list item, I would like it to display 2 characters in the #years .list section.

```js
$(function() {
  var number = $('#actual .list');
  for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    $('#years .list').html(number[i].text().length);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actual">
  <p class="list">Hello</p>
  <p class="list">Hey</p>
  <p class="list">Hi</p>
  <p class="list">Hello</p>
  <p class="list">Hey</p>
  <p class="list">Hi</p>
  <p class="list">Woo</p>
</div>
<div id="years">
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in to an executable snippet, yet I still have absolutely no idea what you're attempting to do. There also seems to be some fairly obvious errors. Could you please edit the question to give a much clearer explanation of your goal

Comment: Also the text lengths don't even match - for example, how is the first string ---> "Hello" equal to 4?

Comment: Thank you for editing. I added an answer for you below.

Comment: I revised the question and I tried to explain it best I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it appears that you are attempting to fill the second set of `p` elements with the length of the text in the associated `p` in the first set.

In this case you have several issues. Firstly accessing a jQuery object by index returns the underlying Element, hence this does not have a `text()` method. Secondly you were setting the `html()` of all the `.list` elements in the loop instead of the one within the current iteration.

To fix this and improve the logic you can provide a function to `text()` which takes the index of the current element as an argument which you can use to compare the `p` elements in the first and second set with `eq()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $list = $('#actual .list');
  $('#years .list').text(function(i) {
    return $list.eq(i).text().length;
  });
});
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="actual">
  <p class="list">Hello</p>
  <p class="list">Hey</p>
  <p class="list">Hi</p>
  <p class="list">Hello</p>
  <p class="list">Hey</p>
  <p class="list">Hi</p>
  <p class="list">Woo</p>
</div>
<div id="years">
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
  <p class="list">#:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all elements with the list class under the #years div to the value so you are overwriting it each time.

Assuming you have a element under #years for each element under #actual you would do this:

```
$(function() {
    var number = $('#actual .list');
        for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            $($('#years .list')[i]).html(number[i].text().length);
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var $number = $('#actual .list');
  for (var i = 0; i < $number.length; i++) {
    var text = $number.eq(i).text();
    $('#years .list').eq(i).html(text.length);
  }
});
```

In the for loop, you should set the HTML of `#years .list` one by one, otherwise they will always be the last one in the for loop.

I prefer using `.eq()` to get the jQuery element, then call the `.html()` (or `.text()`) function to set the content.

For best practice,

- Prepend `$` to the variable name to indicate that it is a jQuery element (`$number`)
- `i` in the for loop should be initialized with `var` for local scope